# Can you force an offline mode? It takes forever to load a page from disk

Tags: google-chrome

I have a machine that is not connected to the internet but I have some documentation saved to the disk in HTML format.

Google Chrome sure enough will open it, but I presume that it's trying to call to the internet at some point so its taking a long time for the offline web pages to load. I think it maybe connecting to Google stats which is in the header, but I don't want to edit every page and remove it.

I downloaded the web pages offline using a downloader and for the most part it works great, all the links are pointed to `file://` so each page loads another page from the disk, but I just wish I could say "if you try the internet return straight away with 404 ... etc" and I believe the page would load faster.

Is there such thing as an offline mode in Chrome and how would I enable it?

Comment: It seems unlikely that it's taking a long time to realize that it's offline. If chrome doesn't have an internet connection, it doesn't just spin it's wheels, but you can probably see what's happening with Fiddler, the Chrome Developer Console, or the Chrome Profiler.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't come across any official description of an **off-line** mode for Google Chrome. Even a [list of command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) has nothing related.

What I do with off-line pages, is to hit the `escape` key. I take my cue from the little url bubble that appears in the lower left, or sometimes lower right, corner of the Chrome window.

Unless the page links to content that has to be constantly refreshed, I'm not missing much.

If you don't like this workaround, another is to just have another browser that does provide a "work off-line" mode. Firefox comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not the real cause of your problem, Chrome detects being offline in no time (just try to open Google on that machine). But if you want to be sure, kill Google Analytics with a `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.google-analytics.com
127.0.0.1 google-analytics.com
127.0.0.1 ssl.google-analytics.com
```

On Windows it's located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\` (hidden folder) and you'll need administrative privileges to edit it. (solution based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/611388/194694), it deserves an upvote!)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could run Fiddler, and block all requests from there.
Checkout the `Rules -> Automatic breakpoints -> before requests` feature as a start.