# Why does www.google-analytics.com hang only when using my primary browser settings?

Tags: browser, web

Accessing [this US government webpage](https://au.usembassy.gov/wp-content/uploads/sites/81/2016/05/form_ds-82.pdf
) hangs on 'waiting for www.google-analytics.com:

It does not hang when in private mode.

It also does not hang if I use noscript to block www.google-analytics.com (see related question, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/611370/tired-of-waiting-for-www-google-analytics-com-can-a-browser-setting-opt-me-o)

Question is, why? Why won't www.google-analytics.com respond when I'm logged into Google?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your link, it responded immediately. BTW, I can't see any scripts inside of that page, just `<!DOCTYPE HTML><HTML></HTML>` while www.google-analytics.com using javascript to track us.

Are you sure that this is exact link you provided?
Copy your link, close browser, reopen it again and paste your link in navigation bar to check it again. Check also settings in `noscript`, may be you accidentally blocked google-analytics.com forever.

Comment: It's the correct link. It does work with www.google-analytics.com blocked, but not without it blocked

Comment: I take that back - it does work now with www.google-analytics.com allowed by no script. I don't know what changed on their site b/w posting this.